# R_Sub setting a timeseries by specific hour of the day

Tags: r, subset

I have a long time series (zoo), 'obs' with one hour timestep and three years data

```
> head(obs)

               time obs   
2009-12-22 01:00:00 23.708
2009-12-22 02:00:00 23.708
2009-12-22 03:00:00 23.708
2009-12-22 04:00:00 23.708
2009-12-22 06:00:00 23.708
2009-12-22 07:00:00 23.708
```

I am only interested in the readings of 01:00:00 of each day and want to subset this series only. Is there anyway to do it? I am already using 'xts' package but couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
subset(obs, as.numeric(format(obs$time, "%H"))==1)
```

This extracts the hours from `obs$time` in a 0 to 24 format, and subsets only the times where it is equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

xts is the right package. What you are interested in is the function

[.xts (Extract subsets of xts Objects)

For example:

```
obs["T01:00/T01:59"]
```

will return all the observation where the "T" time is between 01:00 and 01:59.